# Indent Long Sentence and Number Inside TextView of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textview, indentation

I want to indent long sentences and number inside TextView. The TextView is part of RecyclerView. The text is in `strings.xml`.

I have tried using `LeadingMarginSpan.Standard` and `BulletSpan` but the result is not as expected. Also tried `Html.fromHtml` but the `ol` and `ul` did not show up.

Current Output

```
This is the long sentence which will take more than one line if you see in the mobile phone version of this
application.
    
It is happen because :
1. The screen of the mobile phone is small so the long sentence will automatically break into more than one 
line on the  mobile phone.
2. You have to able to mak the sentence indent in proper way so the reader of this announcement will not have 
difficulty  reading it.
a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi 
repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga 
praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.
b. ...
```

Expected Output

```
This is the long sentence which will take more than one line if you see in the mobile phone version of this
application.
    
It is happen because :
1. The screen of the mobile phone is small so the long sentence will automatically break into more than one 
   line on the  mobile phone.
2. You have to able to mak the sentence indent in proper way so the reader of this announcement will not have 
   difficulty  reading it.
   a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi 
      repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto 
      fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.
   b. ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.